# PLSQL-Measure duration when condition is met

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Assume a table as shown below:

```
time    name availability
10:00   A   100
10:05   A   0
10:10   A   0
10:15   A   0
10:20   A   0
10:25   A   0
10:30   A   100
10:35   A   0
10:40   A   0
10:45   A   100
10:50   A   100
10:55   A   0
11:00   A   100
11:05    A   0
```

I want to calculate the duration of each event where the availability equals zero, meaning not just the count of "0" BUT what was the duration between the first zero and the last zero before the next value becomes again 100.

For example, in my table, I have 3 pair events (up=100,down=0,up) where the first lasts 25min (10:05-10:25), the second 10min and the third 5min. The last zero is not part of an up-down-up event!

Comment: if you want to record time intervals, you should look into interval day to second, which was introduced in 9i to handle time duration issues (along with interval year to month).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be answered with something of pristine beauty, at least not to my knowledge.

It isn't that hard to accomplish, though. You have to become friends with analytic functions, though. in this case: Lag and Lead.

If this is what you want to get (I am positive you can calculate the difference yourself, the interesting part is to get the ranges), then check out the query below:

```
10:00   A   100     
10:05   A   0   10:05   10:25
10:10   A   0   10:05   10:25
10:15   A   0   10:05   10:25
10:20   A   0   10:05   10:25
10:25   A   0   10:05   10:25
10:30   A   100     
10:35   A   0   10:35   10:40
10:40   A   0   10:35   10:40
10:45   A   100     
10:50   A   100     
10:55   A   0   10:55   10:55
11:00   A   100     
11:05   A   0   11:05   11:05
```

---

```
with startTime as
(
  SELECT time
        ,Name
        ,case
           when t.availability = 0 and
           /* see the default value passed to "lag", 
              if nothing gets returned (first row), we return 2 which is > 0 */
                 lag(availability, 1,2) OVER(partition BY Name ORDER BY time) > 0 then 
            time
         end start_time
  FROM   SampleTable t
)
,stopTime as
(
  SELECT time
        ,name
        ,case
           when t.availability = 0 and
           /* see the default value passed to "lead" 
              if nothing gets returned (last row), we return 2 which is > 0*/
                (lead(availability, 1, 2) OVER(partition BY Name ORDER BY time) > 0) then
            time
         end stop_time
  FROM   SampleTable t
)
SELECT t.time
      ,t.Name
      ,t.availability
      ,case
         when t.availability = 0 then
          (SELECT Max(start_time)
           FROM   startTime
           WHERE  start_time is not null
           and    time <= t.time)
       end as start_time
      ,case
         when t.availability = 0 then
          (SELECT Min(stop_time)
           FROM   stopTime
           WHERE  stop_time is not null
           and    time >= t.time)
       end as stop_time
FROM   SampleTable t
ORDER  BY t.time
```

Answer (score 0):

The LAG function can help you:
[Oracle LAG function](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/lag.html)